# jQuery UI Datepicker, set default start of day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

We have a system where we instantiate many .datepicker objects

I know I can set the start date like so

```
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'firstDay', 4); // i.e. Thursday
```

Is there a way of setting this value by default, for all subsequent .datepicker requests (without the need to have to specify the firstDay option at the point of execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lots of options available with  Jquery UI datepicker

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    constrainInput: true,   // prevent letters in the input field
    minDate: new Date(),    // prevent selection of date older than today
    showOn: 'button',       // Show a button next to the text-field
    autoSize: true,         // automatically resize the input field 
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  // Date Format used
    firstDay: 4 // Start with Thursday
})
```

Comment: Super, setDefaults is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Pro's and Con's to both approaches I guess. Setting it inline means you can change it at render point, if for example the Start Day for the user were to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `$.datepicker.setDefaults( options )`. Check [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  firstDay: 4,
});
```

Comment: As above, thank you for your quick answer. setDefaults is what I was after.